# Insert or Update Data in Google Spreadsheet from Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, google-apps-script, oracle-apex

I would like to know how I can insert or update data in a Google Spreadsheet from an Oracle Database please?

Answer (score 2):

Apps Script residing in a spreadsheet container or somewhere else can fetch data from oracle and update your spreadsheet but I don't think there is any simple way to update spreadsheet from Oracle side. For programming, Oracle uses PLSQL but I have not come to any solution yet to use Spreadsheet API with PLSQL.

It would be better to write Apps Script code and which will run by a time driven trigger and look for changes in Oracle table and update the same in spreadsheet.
Here is the reference link to use [JDBC Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/jdbc) in Apps Script.